# Continuity on $\Bbb R$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

$f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ is continuous on $\Bbb R$. $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0$, and $\lim\limits_{x\to-\infty}f(x)=0$.

Prove that $f$ is bounded on $\Bbb R$ and attains either an absolute maximum or an absolute minimum!

Comment: It’s incorrect to say that $f(x)$ is **equal** to $0$ as $x$ tends to something; what you mean is that $\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}f(x)=0$. That is, it’s the **limit** that’s $0$, not some unspecified $f(x)$.

Comment: Have you made any progress on the problem yourself? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: Note : I tried to create a sequence f :[0,1]---R such that |f(x)|<M1 and similarly f:[0,n] such that |f(x)|<Mn...intuitively this sequence eventually is constant and hence convergent(can use the fact as x tends to infinity limf(x)=0)

Comment: I don't know what you mean by M1 and Mn. Do you know that any bounded sequence of reals has a subsequence with a limit?

Comment: yes, but can I use it here?

Comment: @MAB: Thanks for adding something about what you tried.  Unfortunately what you wrote doesn't make much sense (to me).  For starters, $f: [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$is not a sequence: it's a function.  And I don't see anything which is eventually constant here.  Could you think a bit more about what you wrote and try again?

Comment: I'd also like to see a bit of the work you did because, if I understand correctly, that argument seems like it will definitely work when formalized.

Comment: Here sequence is Mn not F! I understand f is a function!Mn is the sequence of upper bounds

Comment: Hint: For boundedness, there are a positive $M$, $N$ such that $|f(x)|\lt 1$ if $x\lt -M$, and also if $x\gt N$. For absolute max or min, you will need a slightly subtler version of the same thing.

Comment: Showing this is what I'm stuck with! and so I consulted you all geniuses!

Answer (score 5):

Here are some hints:

1) Suppose we restrict the domain to $[-N,N]$ for some positive integer $N$.  Then we can simply quote a big theorem to tell us that $f: [-N,N] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is bounded and assumes a minimum and maximum value: what theorem is that?

Thus we can "handle $f$" for small values of $x$.  On the other hand:

2) Since $\lim_{x \rightarrow \pm \infty} f(x) = 0$, this tells us how to "handle $f$" for large values of $x$.

Can you figure out how to put 1) and 2) together?  Try to show the boundedness first.

**Added**: I'll venture one more hint: first choose $N$ such that the maximum $M_N$ of $|f|$ on $[−N,N]$ is positive (it is very easy to handle the case in which there is no such $N$). Then handle the case of very large $x$...so large so that $|f(x)|<M_N$ You are left with an intermediate range to handle, which again you can do using the Extreme Value Theorem.

Comment: I was telling the same thing but on [0,N]...better to write [-N,N] Mn was my upper bound for each interval

Comment: and also Mn is a monotonically increasing sequence, if only I can show it bounded!

Comment: How to mathematically show for very large x? Please professor don't get irritated I'm a beginner in analysis!

Comment: @MAB: It's fine; I'm certainly not irritated.  (Please student don't get irritated as I continue to give hints and not complete answers!)  "For very large $x$" is handled by using the hypothesis that the limit at $\pm \infty$ is $0$.  What does that mean, exactly?

Answer (score 1):

Consider $g(x) := |f(x)|$. $g$ satisfies the conditions of the problem and is a positive function. If it is identically zero, there is not much to prove. So let's assume that for some $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$, $g(x_0) > 0$. As $g$ vanishes at infinity, there exists $N$ such that whenever $|x| \ge N$, $g(x) < \frac{g(x_0)}{2}$. On the compact interval $[-N,N]$, the continuous function $g$ attains absolute maximum which is greater than or equal to $g(x_0) > \frac{g(x_0)}{2}$. Thus $g$ is bounded and attains absolute maximum on $\mathbb{R}$. For $f$, this translates to the fact that $f$ is bounded on $\mathbb{R}$ and attains either an absolute maximum or an absolute minimum.

$f_1(x) := \frac{1}{x^2+1}$ and $f_2(x) := \frac{-1}{x^2+1}$ are examples which show that both absolute maximum and minimum need not be attained.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: The key is showing that $f$ is bounded. If not, assume without loss of generality that it is not bounded above. Then for each $n\in\Bbb N$ there is an $x_n\in\Bbb R$ such that $f(x_n)\ge n$. Consider two possibilities:

- $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ is unbounded. Why is this impossible?
- $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ is bounded and therefore has a convergent subsequence (why?); why is this impossible?

Once you’ve established that $f$ is bounded, let $m=\inf\{f(x):x\in\Bbb R\}$ and $M=\sup\{f(x):x\in\Bbb R\}$. Clearly $m\le 0\le M$; why? If $m=M=0$, the function is constantly $0$ and has an absolute maximum and minimum at every point. If $M>0$, show that there is an $x\in\Bbb R$ such that $f(x)=M$, so that $f$ attains its maximum at $x$. To do this, start by noting that there is a sequence $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ in $\Bbb R$ such that $\langle f(x_n):n\in\Bbb N\rangle\to M$. (Why?) Now do something with $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ and use the fact that $f$ is continuous.

If $m<0$, a similar argument shows that $f$ attains a minimum of $m$ at some point.

Comment: Why xn cannot be unbounded?

Comment: @MAB: Because $\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}f(x)=0$.

Comment: Sir, in the end of your answer, you said "do something with $(x_n)$ and use the fact $f$ is continuous". Sir what to do with $(x_n)$? please can you elaborate.

Comment: @AkashPatalwanshi: Start by showing that $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ is bounded. Then use a basic fact about bounded sequences in $\Bbb R$.

Comment: Sir, i got your hint  But, why should sequence $(x_n)$ is bounded? Is because of $(f(x_n))→M$? How to prove $(x_n)$ is bounded? Because i think it is arbitrary sequence in $\mathbb{R}$? Please help

Comment: @AkashPatalwanshi: You’re not taking advantage of the fact that $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\lim_{x\to-\infty}f(x)=0$. If $f(x_n)\to M$, then $x_n>\frac{M}2$ for sufficiently large $n$, and that means that there is a limit on how big $|x_n|$ can be.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott sir, frankly i am unable to prove $(x_n)$ is bounded yet :-(

Comment: @AkashPatalwanshi: I would really have preferred to leave it as a hint, since it’s now a rather big one. There is an $n_0\in\Bbb N$ such that $f(x_n)>\frac{M}2$ for all $n\ge n_0$, and there is a real $a>0$ such that $f(x)<\frac{M}2$ whenever $|x|>a$. Put these two facts together to show that $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ must be bounded.

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ tends to zero as $x$ tends to infinity, $f$ can be extended to a continuous function on the circle by compactifying $\mathbb{R}$, for example by using the map $x\mapsto \frac{x+i}{x-i}$. By the extreme value theorem a continuous function on a compact attains its maximum.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $g(x)=f(\tan(\pi x/2))$, defined on the open interval $(-1,1)$; then your hypotheses imply that $g$ can be extended to a continuous function $\tilde{g}\colon[-1,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ which, of course, attains a maximum and a minimum.

Therefore $f$, which has the same image as $g$, is bounded. The image of $\tilde{g}$ is $\operatorname{im}(g)\cup\{0\}$. If a minimum is not attained by $f$, it means that the minimum for $\tilde{g}$ is $0$. So either the maximum of $\tilde{g}$ is zero and $f$ is constant, or the maximum of $\tilde{g}$ is greater than $0$, so it's also a maximum for $g$ and for $f$.