# Prove that a function defined with the modulus is holomorphic

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $D=D(0,1)$ and let $f$ be a holomorphic function on $D$ with $f'$ bounded on $D$.

Let $g=(1-|z|) |f'(z)|$

I need to use the maximum modulus principle on $g$ to prove that it's maximum is reached within $D$ but I don't manage to prove that $g$ is holomorphic.

Is that even true that g is holomorphic?

Any help or hint is much appreciated.

Comment: You don't need any maximum modulus principle.

Comment: No, $g$ is not holomorphic. Actually there are not so many holomorphic functions with only real values...

Comment: If $h$ is a bounded, continuous function on $D$, then $g(z)=(1-|z|)|h|$ attains its maximum on $D$. That is all is needed for [your question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2753894/551819).

Comment: Understand first [this argument](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/470241/551819). Your problem is the same, but on the disc.

Comment: I see now your point @totoro.